# Adding JWT sign after inserting new user into SQLite table (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, sqlite, jwt

I'm registering a new user to a SQLite DB.
The relevant part of the route looks like this :

```
 bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send({
        msg: err
      })
    } else {
      db.all(
        `INSERT INTO user (id, username, email, password) VALUES (${getRandomId()}, '${req.body.username}', '${req.body.email}', '${hash}')`,
        (err, result) => {
          if (err) {
            throw err
            return res.status(400).send({
              msg: err
            })
          }
          const token = jwt.sign({
            username: result[0].username,
            userId: result[0].id
          },
          'SECRETKEY', {
            expiresIn: '7d'
          }
        );
```

Obviously i'm trying to access `result[0].username` but it's undefined.
How should I do it right?